# System Tray Menu error MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am Making an Application which will make a dialog as system tray icon after some button press. it is working fine but also i need to open the menu same as dialog contains on Right Click and have written following Code:

```
CMenu pMenu;
pMenu.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU1);
POINT pointCursor;   
::GetCursorPos( &pointCursor );   
pMenu.TrackPopupMenu(TPM_BOTTOMALIGN|TPM_LEFTBUTTON|TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, pointCursor.x, pointCursor.y, this);
```

It is Creating the menu but the **width of the menu is very thin** as shown following:(**Yellow highlighted area is menu**)

[image]

if I add only first **submenu of main menu** then it works well as following code:

```
    CMenu *pMenu = GetMenu();
     POINT pointCursor; 
CMenu *pMenu = GetMenu();
    ::GetCursorPos( &pointCursor );    
    pMenu->GetSubMenu(0)->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_BOTTOMALIGN|TPM_LEFTBUTTON|TPM_RIGHTBUTTON,pointCursor.x,pointCursor.y,this);
```

On applying this code i get following output

[image]

Actually I need the Following menu:

[image]
Kindly Suggest Where i am doing it wrong

Comment: When does the problem occur?  Right clicking in the dialog, or, on the task bar?

Comment: @rrirower i have write down the event of popup menu on right click.

Comment: Is the yellow supposed to show a sub-menu for the "Open Recent User Profile" menu item?  What does it look like "if I add only first submenu of main menu"?

Comment: @rrirower see the question i have added output on sub menu

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now.  So, you want the menu items in the top (eg. "Profile", "Tools", etc.) to show as well.  Right?

Comment: yes it is not appearing but the yellow line is my menu and it is showing submenus but not showing the main menu headings i.e.  "Profile", "Tools", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TrackPopupMenu cannot display the **menu bar** as part of it's work. The menu bar itself is not displayed because TrackPopupMenu requires a handle to a menu, submenu, or shortcut menu.  So, given that, if you really want the same menu structure including the menu bar you've shown, you'll need to create that structure dynamically using CMenu methods.  Or, simply create a new menu resource with a different name that includes the menu bar items as submenus.

Comment: but the yellow line is my menu and it is showing submenus but not showing the main menu headings only i.e. "Profile", "Tools", etc. there should be some method to widen the menu strip.

Comment: i have tried your idea created a new menu and add my main menu to that menu. now i am able to get the exact output but when i maximize i.e. restoring to the dialog then my menu is not shown up as it it was. how to restore the same menu?